# Media Queries inside stylesheet in ie8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I am trying to get @media queries to work within a stylesheet for IE8.

Many people recommend using the following plugin: http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

I am certain I am using it correctly (I am not @import for stylesheets). However it is not working at all in IE8. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated in years and maybe it's not compatible with jQuery 1.7

Does anyone have a working solution for the latest version of jQuery.

Many thanks,

Comment: This is what you need: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: I would also recommend **Respond** as @elclanrs stated. But notice, that it can handle only `min-width` and `max-width` media queries.

Comment: Thank you, Respond did the trick I had not come across it before. First person to post it as an answer gets it marked correct! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @elclanrs stated in the comments use **Respond**. It's a lightweight library that handles `min-width` and `max-width` media queries:

Get it on github: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 0):

u can use Modernizr's mq function to solve it: [link](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq)

quick/simple expample:

```
if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 940px)')) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css" type="text/css" />');
}
```

Comment: From their site: _If a browser does not support media queries at all (eg. oldIE) the mq() will always return false_